# Java, Spring MVC, repository, Maven,

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here is some file which I need to call.

1st user search it by there first_name or last_name or both.

After click on search button we call controller then through controller we call service and through service we call `studentRepository` and through that we call `AbstractRepository.java`'s method i.e. `findByQuery` but how to call that method and retrieve that instance and show the searched name on jsp file?

index.jsp

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/staff/student/searchStudent" method="post">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" name="lastName"  class="form-control input-lg"placeholder="Last Name" required/>
            </div>
            
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" /> 
        </form>
```

studentController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView searchStudent(@RequestParam(name = "firstName", required = true) String firstName,
        @RequestParam(name = "lastName", required = true) String lastName, HttpServletRequest request) {

    studentService.search(firstName, lastName);
    ModelAndView mdlv = getView("add");
    
    return mdlv;
}
```

studentService.java

```
public Student search(String firstName, String lastName)
{
            
    Student student = studentRepository.searchByName(firstName,lastName);
    if(student != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Search Successfully done !");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong entries");
    }
    
    
    
    return student;
    
}
```

studentRepository.java

```
    @Repository("studentRepository")
@Transactional
public class StudentRepository extends AbstractRepository<Student, Long> {
```

AbstractRepository.java

```
    public StudentRepository() {
        super(Student.class);
        }
    }

  public List<T> findByQuery(CriteriaQuery<T> query) {
    return this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `StudentController` (save the found student in the `ModelAndView`):

```
Student student = studentService.search(firstName, lastName);
ModelAndView mdlv = getView("add");
mdlv.addObject("student", student);

return mdlv;
```

And then on the *add* view you can display the student using e.g `${student.name}` (assuming you have getter `getName()`), or any other accessor/getter.